# Por que o limite do tipo "long int" é igual ao do "int`"?

Tags: c, tipagem, memória, int

O limite do tipo `int` é de  2147483647, mas o limite do tipo `long int` também é  2147483647. Por que o limite não aumentou?

Comment: O `long int` se refere a um inteiro sinalizado de 32 bits. O `short int` se refere a um inteiro sinalizado de 16 bits. O `long long int` se refere a um inteiro sinalizado de 64 bits (talvez seja extensão da linguagem/algo não padrão que muitos usam, não tenho certeza). O tipo `int` _pode_ se referir a um `short int` ou a um `long int`, dependente de implementação do compilador

Comment: Veja em limits.h os valores mínimo e máximo para os diversos tipos de inteiro em seu ambiente.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

> O limite do tipo `int` é de 2147483647.

Não essa informação é falsa, ele pode ter esse limite, mas nada garante isso. Pode ter menos que isto.

> o limite do tipo `long int` também é 2147483647

Também não é verdade, esse é o limite mínimo que este tipo deve ter, mas ele pode ter mais.

> Porque o limite não aumentou?

Isto não faz sentido. A única coisa que a especificação diz é que o `long int` não pode ser menor que que o `int`. Não tem nada que aumentar.

O comentário do Jefferson está parcialmente certo, falta dizer que é este é o tamanho mínimo. A frase final não faz sentido, esses tipos não se misturam, talvez ele quisesse dizer algo um pouco diferente disto e ficou confuso.